# How can I add score when I pass through the hurdles and end a game if my object touches the hurdle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android programming and was trying to build this simple game(resembles flappy bird).So, I wanted to know how to add score when my ball passes through the gap and end my game when the ball touches the hurdle.

I tried taking some help from Youtube but it was too complex for me to understand right now.

The score should increase when I pass through a gap and the game should end if I touch the hurdle with my ball.[image: The image shows the interface of the game.]

JAVA CODE:

```
package com.company.yash.ball;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;  
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView Scorelabel;
TextView Startlabel;
ImageView box;
ImageView danger;
ImageView danger2;

//size
private int frameheight;
private int boxsize;
private int screenheight;
private int screenwidth;

//position
int boxY;
int dangerY;
int dangerX;
int danger2Y;
int danger2X;


//class initialization
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Timer timer =new Timer();

private boolean action_flg = false;
private boolean start_flg =  false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Scorelabel=findViewById(R.id.score);
    Startlabel=findViewById(R.id.begin);
    box=findViewById(R.id.box);
    danger=findViewById(R.id.danger);
    danger2=findViewById(R.id.danger2);

    //get screen size
    WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size =new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    screenheight = size.x;
    screenwidth = size.y;

    danger.setX(-400);
    danger.setY(-400);
    danger2.setY(-400);
    danger2.setX(-400);

}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){

    if(start_flg==false){

        start_flg =true;

        FrameLayout frame = findViewById(R.id.frame);
        frameheight = frame.getHeight();
        boxY = (int) box.getY();
        boxsize = box.getHeight();
        Startlabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        changePos();
                    }
                });
            }
        },0,20);

    }
        else{
        if(me.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                action_flg = true;
            }
                else if (me.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                action_flg = false;

        }

    return true;
}

public void changePos(){

    //check hit
    hitCheck();

    //danger
    dangerX -= 18;
    if(dangerX<0){
        dangerX = screenwidth + 20;
        dangerY = 0;
    }

    danger.setX(dangerX);
    danger.setY(dangerY);

    //danger2
    danger2X -= 18;
    if(danger2X<0){
        danger2X = screenwidth + 20;
        danger2Y = frameheight - danger2.getHeight();
    }
    danger2.setX(danger2X);
    danger2.setY(danger2Y);

    //move box
    if (action_flg==true)
    {
        //touching
        boxY -= 20;
    }
    else
    {
        //release
        boxY += 20;
    }

    //check box pos
    if(boxY<0)boxY=0;
    if(boxY>(frameheight-boxsize))boxY=(frameheight-boxsize);

    box.setY(boxY);
}

public void hitCheck(){
    //if user touches the danger then activity restarts

    int dngrX = dangerX + danger.getWidth();
    int dngrY = dangerY + danger.getHeight();
}

}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Score : 0"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"

    />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2196F3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/begin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="TAP TO BEGIN"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/box"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/boxa"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/danger"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:scaleY="-1"
        android:src="@drawable/danger" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/danger2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/danger" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @Ashish I uploaded please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Where you wrote:

```
if(danger2X<0){
    danger2X = screenwidth + 20;
    danger2Y = frameheight - danger2.getHeight();
    // Increase your score here.
}
```

This means that the `danger2` is to the left of the screen, and moving back to the right, so the player has "dodged" it. Increase your score then.

But, I advise you to learn some best practices before continuing. Camel Case, how to name stuff, or even the flow of the application, before code.

Comment: I appreciate your answer buddy. And yes, I know I really need to work hard on my basics first but I was just trying things maybe i escalated too quickly.

Comment: It happens. What I meant is google Camel Case, on how to name variables. Also, try to think of it as a "card game", or even, try to speak the flow out loud, then doing. Such as a "frame", or a "second" is: `box` hits a barrier? loose. Else, move barriers, add points, points equals max for level? win